# How Do I Convert an Integer to a String in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, string, type-conversion, integer

How do I convert the **integer** value "45" into the **string** value "45" in Excel VBA?

Answer (score 291, accepted):

`CStr(45)` is all you need (the Convert String function)

Comment: this will not work for e+ converted numbers! i.e 7.7685099559e+11 will be shown as "7.7685099559e+11" not as expected: "776850995590"
So I rather to say this will be more generic one:`CStr(CDbl(***))`

Comment: It may answer the question's needs, but it's also incomplete and insufficient in some circumstances. Often (e.g. for file-naming purposes) you might want to create zero-prefixed numbers, such that `7` becomes `007`.  You may also want to specify the number of decimals or include thousand separators. If these details are important to you: https://www.excelfunctions.net/vba-format-function.html

Answer (score 102):

Try the CStr() function

```
Dim myVal as String
Dim myNum as Integer

myVal = "My number is:"
myVal = myVal & CStr(myNum)
```

Answer (score 57):

Most times, you won't need to "convert"; VBA will do safe implicit type conversion for you, *without* the use of converters like  `CStr`.

The below code works without any issues, because the variable is of Type String, and **implicit type conversion is done for you automatically!**

```
Dim myVal As String
Dim myNum As Integer

myVal = "My number is: "
myVal = myVal & myNum
```

Result:

> "My number is: 0"

You don't even have to get that fancy, this works too:

```
Dim myString as String
myString = 77
```

> "77"

**The only time you WILL need to convert is when the variable Type is ambiguous** (e.g., Type Variant, or a Cell's `Value` (which *is* Variant)).

Even then, you won't have to use `CStr` function if you're compounding with another String variable or constant. Like this:

```
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "My favorite number is " & 7
```

> "My favorite number is 7"

So, really, the only *rare* case is when you really want to store an integer value, into a variant or Cell value, when *not* also compounding with another string (which is a pretty rare side case, I might add):

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 7
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = i
```

> 7

```
Dim i as Integer
i = 7
Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = CStr(i)
```

> "7"

Comment: I don't understand why this answer doesn't have more votes, given it is true. It is worth noting that type conversion is not *always* carried out, it depends on the operator in use. For example the + operation will not always widen an integer to a string.

Comment: @MarkCh I know this is old, but... perhaps because VBA's obnoxious implicit conversions and default member calls are what makes so much VBA code frail, surprising and bug-prone? There wouldn't be half as many VBA questions on SO if it wasn't of implicit conversions, implicit accessibility, implicit default member access, implicit 1-based arrays with `Option Base 1`, implicit typing with `Def[Type]` (boy that's EVIL!), implicit... you get it - the only good implicit thing in VBA is the implicit call syntax that made the explicit `Call` obsolete.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, the function CString was not found.
But adding an empty string to the value works, too.

```
Dim Test As Integer, Test2 As Variant
Test = 10
Test2 = Test & ""
//Test2 is now "10" not 10
```

Comment: Nobody talked about `CString`, which is a VB.NET function. Concatenating an empty string literal to make a string is a pretty lame conversion method. Use `CStr` for explicit type conversions - this is an implicit type conversion and raises eyebrows of anyone reading that code. Sorry I found this answer so late after it was posted, I wish I could have downvoted it much earlier.

Answer (score 3):

The shortest way without declaring the variable is with [Type Hints](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/2960/type-hints) :

```
s$ =  123   ' s = "123"
i% = "123"  ' i =  123
```

This will not compile with `Option Explicit`.  The types will not be `Variant` but `String` and `Integer`

Answer (score 3):

If the string you're pulling in happens to be a hex number such as E01, then Excel will translate it as 0 even if you use the CStr function, and even if you first deposit it in a String variable type.  One way around the issue is to append ' to the beginning of the value.

For example, when pulling values out of a Word table, and bringing them to Excel:

```
strWr = "'" & WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
    Sub NumToText(ByRef sRng As String, Optional ByVal WS As Worksheet)
    '---Converting visible range form Numbers to Text
        Dim Temp As Double
        Dim vRng As Range
        Dim Cel As Object

        If WS Is Nothing Then Set WS = ActiveSheet
            Set vRng = WS.Range(sRng).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
            For Each Cel In vRng
                If Not IsEmpty(Cel.Value) And IsNumeric(Cel.Value) Then
                    Temp = Cel.Value
                    Cel.ClearContents
                    Cel.NumberFormat = "@"
                    Cel.Value = CStr(Temp)
                End If
            Next Cel
    End Sub


    Sub Macro1()
        Call NumToText("A2:A100", ActiveSheet)
    End Sub
```

[Reffer: MrExcel.com – Convert numbers to text with VBA](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/convert-numbers-to-text-with-vba.30232/)

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is good for smaller numbers, most importantly while you are taking data from excel sheets. as the bigger numbers will automatically converted to scientific numbers i.e. e+10.
So I think this will give you more general answer. I didn't check if it have any downfall or not.

```
CStr(CDbl(#yourNumber#))
```

this will work for e+ converted numbers! as the just `CStr(7.7685099559e+11)` will be shown as "7.7685099559e+11" not as expected: "776850995590" So I rather to say my answer will be more generic result.

Regards,
M

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it is to splice two parsed sections of the numerical value together:

```
Cells(RowNum, ColumnNum).Value = Mid(varNumber,1,1) & Mid(varNumber,2,Len(varNumber))
```

I have found better success with this than `CStr()` because `CStr()` doesn't seem to convert decimal numbers that came from variants in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a valid integer value and your requirement is to compare values, you can simply go ahead with the comparison as seen below.

```
Sub t()

Dim i As Integer
Dim s  As String

' pass
i = 65
s = "65"
If i = s Then
MsgBox i
End If

' fail - Type Mismatch
i = 65
s = "A"
If i = s Then
MsgBox i
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth adding a trim to your conversion too, as integers convert with a leading space for inferred (positive sign) and applied (negative sign) values.

For comparison:

1/

```
lsDogsAge = "Barker is " & Cstr(liAgeInteger) & "years old"
```

2/

```
lsDogsAge = "Barker is " & Trim(Cstr(liAgeInteger)) & "years old"
```

1/ Barker is__7

2/ Barker is_7

Ironically this forum's software automatically truncates double spaces, so I've use underscores