# How to pass a number as string argument in workbook object (excel)

Tags: vba, excel, sku

I am using a for loop to process data of 300 SKUs with some of them having SKU code as purely numeral. The raw data for each SKU is in separate file with both the workbook and worksheet name same as the SKU code.
Error I am facing is index out of range as in:

`Workbooks(wbnamex).Sheets(wbnamex).Cells(k, 2)`

wbnamex contains SKU code and the ones as numerals are resulting in error. The object workbook is taking it as serial number rather than name.

How to go pass the purely numeral SKU code as String?

Comment: did you try using a string like this: " dim s as string", and then "s=wbnamex", Workbooks(s).Sheets(s).Cells(k, 2)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How Do I Convert an Integer to a String in Excel VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11595226/how-do-i-convert-an-integer-to-a-string-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Use `CStr` on the workbook range?

Comment: I believe you should be adding the file extension to the workbook's filename. Try `?thisworkbook.name` in the VBE's Immediate window.

Comment: Are workbooks opened? You must do `Workbooks.Open(xxx)` before using `Workbook(xxx)`.

Comment: @TonyM wbnamex was declared as String variable. The SKUs with codes such as S12345 are not giving error. Only something as 12345 are giving error.

Comment: @ThomasJager Yes this solved it. Thanks

Comment: @Dave  Yes this solved it. Thanks.

Comment: @LS_ᴅᴇᴠ Two files are opened at a time within the loop, I guess this won't work. Anyhow Cstr () solved my problem

Comment: @jeeped Nope, not required when the file is open

Answer (score 0):

This is something that will do the job:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strName     As String
    Dim wb          As Workbook
    Dim wsAny       As Worksheet
    Dim ws          As Worksheet

    strName = "Text"

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & strName & ".xlsm")

    For Each wsAny In wb.Worksheets
        If wsAny.Name = strName Then
            Set ws = wsAny
        End If
    Next wsAny

    Debug.Print ws.Cells(1, 1)

End Sub
```

You need an excel file named `Text.xlsm` with a Worksheet named `Text` as well. Then it will show you the Value of the A1 cell of this worksheet of this workbook.

There are other ways to do it, but this one works. The `Text` file should be in the same folder as the file, in which this code is present.  The Excel file `Text` should be closed as well.

You can edit the code further, to make it work for other folders and with a file, that is already opened.

Comment: This code will help in another problem of mine. But for the original question passing the argument within Cstr() will solve the purpose. Eg.: Workbook(Cstr(wbname)).Sheets(Cstr(wbname)).cells (k, 10). Thanks anyways